# In Azure, while enabling Application Insight, getting message Resource group could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-functions

While studying Azure 204 from Microsoft azure docs,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-serverless-logic-with-azure-functions/4-creating-and-executing-an-azure-function

I have created new function app esclator-function-{name} as asked in documentation.
I am also able to create a function and Test/Run it in Azure portal mode with "Run" button and also in postman using function url.

[image]

Now I want to monitor it using Application Insight. So as instructed in article, I've choosed Application Insight from Settings and clicked "Turn on Application Insight" button , kept the default settings and clicked "Apply" and then "Yes" buttons.
But now when I see in "Notifications" from top right icons, I get message
"Deployment validation failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: Resource group '**DefaultResourceGroup-CID' could not be found.**"

Also the "Apply Changes" shows "**10% Completed**" progress all time, it don't proceed further.
So I am not able to proceed to the article further, I will apricate the workaround if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, while enabling Application Insight, getting message Resource group could not be found

As per the below Image You need to create new resource group or set the existing resource group and you need to enable Application Sight extensions and them you need to apply it.

[image]

For further information check  [Enable application Insights Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration)
Also,
Check [How to configure for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think here issue is, I am using Azure Sandbox, which don't have permission to create new resource. 
As I am getting message, while creating new resource group "You do not have permissions to create resource groups under subscription c5e3db12-9c48-4e72-9840-6dc393c09268."